# When typing long texts, textview appends empty spaces proportional to the input

Tags: ios, swift

[the empty space on the end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnBEo.jpg)I am taking the size of my text view text (the text view that I am writing on) and setting it equal to the size of the text view that I am displaying it. But it if write longer text it shows longer empty space in my text view when I post it. I made the code for the size of my text view by measuring the content.height of the textV that i AM writing on.

```
} else if identifier == "save" {
        print("Save button tapped")

        if textViewWrite.text == "" {
            print("text empty")
        }
        else{

            print("\(textViewWrite.contentSize.height)")



            let size: CGSize = textViewWrite.sizeThatFits(CGSize.init(width: textViewWrite.frame.size.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
            let insets: UIEdgeInsets = textViewWrite.textContainerInset;
            let relevantHeight = size.height - insets.top - insets.bottom;

            let text = Post(texts: "String", textHeight: relevantHeight, textWidth: textViewWrite.contentSize.width)
            PostService.create(text: self.textViewWrite.text!, height: Int(textViewWrite.contentSize.height), width: Int(view.frame.width) )
            print("\(textViewWrite.contentSize.height)")

            // 1
            let HomeViewController = segue.destination as! HomeViewController
            // 2
            HomeViewController.posts.append(text)

        }
        textViewWrite.text = ""
    }
}
```

Comment: Question sounds like a tongue twister with lots of texts.

Comment: To make this clear, I have 2 text View.  1 = the text View that i am writing the post on (textView).   2 = the text View that I am displaying the post (textViewWrite).      Now if I write longer text in the first  textView it posts the post but it also post longer empty space at the 2nd textV

Comment: @MahdiaDaqiq Can you provide a screen shot of this?

Comment: @Stefan i added image at the top u can click of the line empty space and see the image

Comment: Okay correct me if I'm wrong. You want a self sizing text view that is sized based on it's text, which it is getting from another text view. Is this correct?

Comment: yes, that is wright.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the method you are using used before, however for your purposes, I think it's best to use [layout constraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html). It's a lot easier in my opinion.

What you want to do is use layout constraints to constrain the height property of the receiving text view.

In your receiving text view try setting up layout constraints like so...

```
let captionContainer: UIView = {
    let c = UIView()
    c.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    c.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    c.layer.cornerRadius = 6
    return c
}()

let caption: UITextView = {
    let c = UITextView()
    c.textAlignment = .left
    c.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 14)
    c.isScrollEnabled = false
    c.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return c
}()

func setupCaption() {

    view.addSubview(captionContainer)
    view.addSubview(caption)

    //Container Constratins
    captionContainer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250).isActive = true
    captionContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: caption.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
    captionContainer.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    captionContainer.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    //Caption Constraints
    caption.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250).isActive = true
    caption.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    caption.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    // This constraint controls the maximum height the caption can have.
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: caption, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .lessThanOrEqual, toItem: view, attribute: .height, multiplier: 0.25, constant: 0).isActive = true
}
```

Then set the caption text to whatever the textfield or textview you are using for user input.

Good luck.